# What if a file does not exist in local storage for angular.js ngStorage?

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

(javascript)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']);
app.config(function($scope, $localStorageProvider){
  var userlogstatus = $localStorageProvider.get('userloggedin');
  if (userlogstatus === 'null') {
    $scope.loggedinout = 'partials/pagelink.html';
  } else {
    $scope.loggedinout = 'partials/anotherpage.html';
  }
};
```

(html)

```
<div ng-include="'{{loggedinout}}'"></div>
```

The code mentioned above is not working. The value of `userlogstatus` is taken as `null` in javascript because that file does not exist in local storage of my website. Please correct the code mentioned above and help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably correct this line:

```
if (userlogstatus === 'null')
```

to this:

```
if (userlogstatus === null)
```

Comment: sorry, this code is not working I have already tried with this.

Comment: Did you check from Chrome debugger(F12) -> Resources -> Local Storage, if your data is there?

Comment: I have to use the above code even when the key mentioned, i.e., userloggedin does not exist. @asdf_enel_hak